# Expand UIImageView to full screen from within UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiimageview

I have a `UIImageView` within a `UITableViewCell` and want to expand it to fill the full screen, I have setup my `UIGestureRecognizer` and am using this code to expand the frame:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{
        [self.ImageView setFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]];
}];
```

However the `UIImageView` will only expand to fill the `UITableViewCell` and does not fill the full screen.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Dont use the same imageView because cells clipsToBounds is set to Yes so view outside the cell bound will not visible. Check for my answer to implement ur feature.

Answer (score 9):

> cells clipsToBounds is set to Yes, so view outside the cell bound will
>   not visible

Following method will help u to get image in cell to full Screen then get it back to same place.

You need to add gestureRecognizer to imageView and set selector as cellImageTapped

Declare UIImageView *temptumb,fullview; as instance variable.

```
- (void)cellImageTapped:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {
    NSLog(@"%@", [gestureRecognizer view]);
    //create new image
    temptumb=(UIImageView *)gestureRecognizer.view;
    //temptumb=thumbnail;
    fullview=[[UIImageView alloc]init];
      [fullview setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];
    fullview.image = [(UIImageView *)gestureRecognizer.view image];
        CGRect point=[self.view convertRect:gestureRecognizer.view.bounds fromView:gestureRecognizer.view];
    [fullview setFrame:point];

    [self.view addSubview:fullview];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                     animations:^{
                         [fullview setFrame:CGRectMake(0,
                                                       0,
                                                       self.view.bounds.size.width,
                                                       self.view.bounds.size.height)];
                     }];
    UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(fullimagetapped:)];
    singleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
    singleTap.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
    [fullview addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];
    [fullview setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
}
- (void)fullimagetapped:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {

    CGRect point=[self.view convertRect:temptumb.bounds fromView:temptumb];

    gestureRecognizer.view.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                     animations:^{
                         [(UIImageView *)gestureRecognizer.view setFrame:point];
                     }];
    [self performSelector:@selector(animationDone:) withObject:[gestureRecognizer view] afterDelay:0.4];

}

-(void)animationDone:(UIView  *)view
{
    [fullview removeFromSuperview];
    fullview=nil;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`UITableViewCell` only expand when **reloaddata** or **reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation**
otherwise it not change size in table,Simply you add `UIImageView` in self.view and hide image view,when tap the cell image to change image view image after hide image view when close full view