# UICollectionView full screen zoom on UICollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, zooming, fullscreen

How can you zoom in on a `UICollectionViewCell` so that it will be displayed full screen? I have extended `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` and in my view controller when a cell is tapped I'm doing this:

```
CGPoint pointInCollectionView = [gesture locationInView:self.collectionView];
NSIndexPath *selectedIndexPath = [self.collectionView indexPathForItemAtPoint:pointInCollectionView];
UICollectionViewCell *selectedCell = [self.collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:selectedIndexPath];

NSLog(@"Selected cell %@", selectedIndexPath);
```

Not really sure where to go from here. Should the `UICollectionView` be responsible of showing the zoomed in cell? Or should I create a new view controller that displays the content of the cell (an image) in full screen?

Comment: You need to go for anotherviewcontroller to show the image in detail

Comment: It would surely be a lot easier to either create a new controller and push/modal to that, or just create a new view and show it over the current collection view. Modifying your cell to expand just sounds like an unnecessary headache.

Comment: @Stonz2 I would very much like to have the expanding effect. The Facebook app on iOS does it in the albums.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I took the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21242805/expand-uiimageview-to-full-sceren-from-within-uitableviewcell) and modified it slightly to work with a collection view instead. I also added a transparent gray background to hide the original view a bit (assuming the image doesn't take up the entire frame).

```
@implementation CollectionViewController
{
    UIImageView *fullScreenImageView;
    UIImageView *originalImageView;
}

...

// in whatever method you're using to detect the cell selection

CGPoint pointInCollectionView = [gesture locationInView:self.collectionView];
NSIndexPath *selectedIndexPath = [self.collectionView indexPathForItemAtPoint:pointInCollectionView];
UICollectionViewCell *selectedCell = [self.collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:selectedIndexPath];

originalImageView = [selectedCell imageView]; // or whatever cell element holds your image that you want to zoom

fullScreenImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
[fullScreenImageView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];

fullScreenImageView.image = [originalImageView image];
// ***********************************************************************************
// You can either use this to zoom in from the center of your cell
CGRect tempPoint = CGRectMake(originalImageView.center.x, originalImageView.center.y, 0, 0);
// OR, if you want to zoom from the tapped point...
CGRect tempPoint = CGRectMake(pointInCollectionView.x, pointInCollectionView.y, 0, 0);
// ***********************************************************************************
CGRect startingPoint = [self.view convertRect:tempPoint fromView:[self.collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:selectedIndexPath]];
[fullScreenImageView setFrame:startingPoint];
[fullScreenImageView setBackgroundColor:[[UIColor lightGrayColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.9f]];

[self.view addSubview:fullScreenImageView];

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.4
                 animations:^{
                     [fullScreenImageView setFrame:CGRectMake(0,
                                                   0,
                                                   self.view.bounds.size.width,
                                                   self.view.bounds.size.height)];
                 }];

UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(fullScreenImageViewTapped:)];
singleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
singleTap.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
[fullScreenImageView addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];
[fullScreenImageView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];

...

- (void)fullScreenImageViewTapped:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {

    CGRect point=[self.view convertRect:originalImageView.bounds fromView:originalImageView];

    gestureRecognizer.view.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                     animations:^{
                         [(UIImageView *)gestureRecognizer.view setFrame:point];
                     }];
    [self performSelector:@selector(animationDone:) withObject:[gestureRecognizer view] afterDelay:0.4];

}

-(void)animationDone:(UIView  *)view
{
    [fullScreenImageView removeFromSuperview];
    fullScreenImageView = nil;
}
```

Comment: Great. This is what I was searching for. works like a charm. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use another layout (similar to the one you already have) wherein the item size is larger, and then do `setCollectionViewLayout:animated:completion:` on the collectionView.

You don't need a new view controller. Your datasource remains the same. You can even use the same cell Class, just make sure that it knows when to layout things for a larger cell content size, and when not to.

I'm quite sure that's how Facebook does it in Paper, as there is no reloading of the content, i.e. `[collectionView reloadData]` never seems to be called (would have caused flickering and resetting of the scroll offset, etc). This seems to be the most straight forward possible solution.

```
CGPoint pointInCollectionView = [gesture locationInView:self.collectionView];
NSIndexPath *selectedIndexPath = [self.collectionView indexPathForItemAtPoint:pointInCollectionView];
UICollectionViewCell *selectedCell = [self.collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:selectedIndexPath];

NSLog(@"Selected cell %@", selectedIndexPath);

__weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;

[self.collectionView setCollectionViewLayout:newLayout animated:YES completion:^{

    [weakSelf.collectionView scrollToItemAtIndexPath:selectedIndexPath atScrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionCenteredHorizontally animated:NO];

}];
```

Comment: Paper isn't doing that - their gesture is "interactive". The user's gesture controls the animation. As far as I can tell, nobody has really figured it out open-source wise yet, but should theoretically be possible with Pop/AsyncDisplayKit.

Comment: @chug2k definitely possible with https://github.com/wtmoose/TLLayoutTransitioning by utilizing the `setTransitionProgress:time:` method.  We've implemented something similar in the past using the aforementioned OSP.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **MWPhotoBrowser**, which is suitable for your problem. It supports Grid with Tap to Zoom functionality. you can get it from [here](https://github.com/mwaterfall/MWPhotoBrowser)

Grid

In order to properly show the grid of thumbnails, you must ensure the property enableGrid is set to YES, and implement the following delegate method:

```
(id <MWPhoto>)photoBrowser:(MWPhotoBrowser *)photoBrowser thumbPhotoAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index;
```

The photo browser can also start on the grid by enabling the startOnGrid property.