# iOS Programming How to show image fullscreen when user tap on ImageView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview

I want to show image in full screen when user tap on it. 
Can anyone help me please?
My ImageView is in TableViewCell.
Here is what i've tried:

---

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    ImageListTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    cell.propertyImageView.frame = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds;
    cell.propertyImageView.image = [imageList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}
```

Comment: check this ans: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21260074/4831524

Comment: Your code does not contain code that shows full screen image. How do you want to show a full screen image? A layer on top of table view, or to a new view controller?

Comment: Yes on a top layer on the tableView.Thank you ! Can you please help me?

Answer (score 2):

It is quite easy like this:

```
-(void)removeImage {

    UIImageView *imgView = (UIImageView*)[self.view viewWithTag:100];
    [imgView removeFromSuperview];
}

-(void)addImageViewWithImage:(UIImage*)image {

    UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
    imgView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
    imgView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    imgView.image = image;
    imgView.tag = 100;
    UITapGestureRecognizer *dismissTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(removeImage)];
    dismissTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
    [imgView addGestureRecognizer:dismissTap];
    [self.view addSubview:imgView];
}
```

Call from your table delegate like this:

```
    -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

   [self addImageViewWithImage:[imageList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    }
```